# Allow script initiated windows without size or position constraint

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there any way to enable Internet Explorer IE property "Allow script initiated windows without size or position constraint" through script/Csharp?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no way to do this.

This is a browser feature and most browser features cannot be turned on/off in scripts.

---

As an aside, it would make no sense for you to be able to disable a security feature from a script.  This feature is trying to protect the user from malicious scripts and it would be useless if the malicious scripts could disable the protection.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. But I think there should be someway to display only user defined titles in the popup window. When this option disabled, IE 8 displays full url in the title section.I tried with document.title/<title> options to display only user defined title, but no luck.